# Display exception inside a <div> block

Tags: php

Is it possible to display an exception message in a particular HTML `<div>` block?

```php
catch (Exception $e) {
    // display message in <div> block here
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

**EDIT:** Suppose I have an `index.php` file and a `<div>` element called `error`. I want to show all exceptions in `<div id="error">...</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
catch (Exception $e) {
        // want to display message on html div block.
        echo sprintf('<div>%s</div>', $e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Uh? Sorry, your question is not 100% clear...

```
<?php echo '<div>'.$e->getMessage().'</div>'; ?>
```

Comment: suppose I have index.php file. and there is div block called error. I want to show all exception on  `<div id="error">   </div> `

Answer (score 0):

You can store `$e->getMessage()` in a variable and echo it later.

```
try {
    /* do something */
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

/* do something else */

if ( isset($error) ) {
    echo "<div>{$error}</div>";
}
```